# Can XML element have '$' sign in the value?

Tags: xml

Can an XML element contain $ sign in the value:

```
<root>
<data>This is a $ sign.</data>
</root>
```

Comment: Did it break for you?

Comment: Why don't you tell us the error that popped up against which you are asking this question?

Comment: @PSL: Just because it works does not mean it meets the spec. XML processors are different, and if you break your end of the contract the way in which they break may change from processor to processor or from processor version to processor version. A valid implementation of undefined behavior is "appear to work". That doesn't mean the document is valid.

Comment: Let's say the document contains just the above (and of course the xml preprocessor), in that case, is it valid?

Answer (score 4):

The [XML 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets) says:

> CharData    ::=    [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)

which means that only `<` and `&` are disallowed for consideration as character data. (So long as the data meets the character set requirements, of course, which is any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, U+FFFE, and U+FFFF)

Of course, XML is a very basic specification of a document tree; the program you want to read the XML document may impose other requirements.

Comment: Billy this you are defining when you want to define your own specifications.  Default XML ver 1.1 do allow  <  or & symbols without any problem and issue. and all XML parsers honor them if defined them within CDATA.  you can try the sample code I posted.

Comment: @Vinay: I'm talking about outside of a CDATA section. A CDATA section may contain anything so long as a character meets the basic character set requirements, and does not contain the literal string `]]>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes 
You can use cdata casting

```
<root>
<data><![CDATA[This is a $ sign.]]></data>
</root>
```

Comment: This has no basis in the specification. That's also not a valid CDATA section; CDATA must start with `<![CDATA[`, not just `cdata[`.

Comment: Of course, a CDATA section is shooting a mouse with an elephant gun for a `$` character. (Considering a plain literal $ is fine inside a normal text section)

Answer (score 0):

Yes

YesYesYesYesYesYesYesYesYesYesYesYesYesYesYes (repeated only because SO won't accept short answers).